SSL Certificate Issue During Kivy App Build with Buildozer and Python-for-Android
I am encountering an issue when building a Kivy application using Buildozer. During the build process, I am getting an SSL certificate error related to downloading the required files from GitHub.
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
Context:
I am using Buildozer to create APK files for a Kivy application.
I am working in WSL2 with Ubuntu.
The error occurs when trying to download libffi version 3.4.2 and other dependencies.
Steps I’ve already taken:
Updated root certificates: sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates.
Updated Python and pip to the latest version.
Updated Buildozer and Python-for-Android to the latest versions.
Checked proxy settings and tried disabling it.
Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?
Are there alternative ways to manually download the required files?
How can I temporarily disable SSL verification to continue the build (if it's safe)?
Development Environment:
OS: WSL2 with Ubuntu.
Python version: 3.10.
Buildozer version: latest stable.
Python-for-Android version: latest stable.
